# Get back to my app after marker click on google maps

Tags: android, google-maps, maps, marker

I had a problem in my app development. After a button click i can open Google Maps with current position of the user.

```
location_selection.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                Location gpsLocation = appLocationService.getLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                Location nwLocation = appLocationService.getLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

                if (gpsLocation != null) {

                    latitude = gpsLocation.getLatitude();
                    longitude = gpsLocation.getLongitude();

                } else if(nwLocation != null) {

                    latitude = nwLocation.getLatitude();
                    longitude = nwLocation.getLongitude();

                } else {

                    Toast hint = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please turn on GPS/Network", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    hint.show();

                }

                if(latitude != 0 && longitude != 0) {

                    Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
                            Uri.parse("geo:0,0?q="+latitude+","+longitude));
                    startActivity(intent);

                }

            }

        });
```

What i want to do is to retrieve coordinates and address of the marker that the user set after google maps has been open, and get back with this data to my app closing google map. But I really don't know how to do that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To obtain address from latitude and longitude of your current location

Take a look at this link 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/

Look for "Reverse Geocoding (Address Lookup)" might help

You will have to make http call to the google Geocoding API with your lat and long which retrieve JSON that contains addresses you interested about the location.  Sort your JSON in java into readable text.

What i want to do is to retrieve coordinates
I am not sure what you meant in here,  since lat and long are already in the your code above

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for the answer. When i said "retreive coordinates" i mean that i can open Maps on the current coordinates, but i want to retreive the coordinates of a new marker that the user select in Maps, and its relative address, and close maps with NEW_LATITUDE,NEW_LONGITUDE, ADDRESS_REFERRED_TO_THIS_NEW_LOCATION back to my app.

Comment: To get the coordinate from the user when the user click on the map, override the onMapClick method which implement OnMapClickListener. Use these coordinate to make Geocoding API call to get the address